# Getting "enabled the security manager warning" in leetcode

Tags: java, data-structures

This was the problem to build binary tree using preorder and inorder

And I get

> WARNING:A command line option has enabled the Security Manager

```
public TreeNode buildTree(int[] preorder, int[] inorder) {

    Map<Integer,Integer> inorder_map=new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<inorder.length-1;i++)
    {
        inorder_map.put(inorder[i],i);
    }
    TreeNode root=buildTreeHelp(preorder,0,preorder.length-1,inorder,0,inorder.length-1,inorder_map);
    return root;
}

public  TreeNode buildTreeHelp(int[] preOrder,int preStart,int preEnd,int[] inOrder,int inStart,int inEnd,Map<Integer , Integer> inorder_Map)
{
    
    if(preStart>preEnd||inStart>inEnd)
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    TreeNode root =new TreeNode(preOrder[preStart]);
    
    int inRoot=inorder_Map.get(root.val); // where I get warning
    int nums_in_left=inRoot-inStart;
    
    root.left=buildTreeHelp(preOrder,preStart+1,preStart+nums_in_left,inOrder,inStart,inRoot-1,inorder_Map);
    root.right=buildTreeHelp(preOrder,preStart+nums_in_left+1,preEnd,inOrder,inRoot+1,inEnd,inorder_Map);
 
    
    return root;
    
    
}
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe1zZ.png)

This is someone's code from discussion form, which is executing.

```
public TreeNode buildTree(int[] preorder, int[] inorder) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> inMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i < inorder.length; i++) {
        inMap.put(inorder[i], i);
    }

    TreeNode root = buildTree(preorder, 0, preorder.length - 1, inorder, 0, inorder.length - 1, inMap);
    return root;
}

public TreeNode buildTree(int[] preorder, int preStart, int preEnd, int[] inorder, int inStart, int inEnd, Map<Integer, Integer> inMap) {
    if(preStart > preEnd || inStart > inEnd) return null;

    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(preorder[preStart]);
    int inRoot = inMap.get(root.val);
    int numsLeft = inRoot - inStart;

    root.left = buildTree(preorder, preStart + 1, preStart + numsLeft, inorder, inStart, inRoot - 1, inMap);
    root.right = buildTree(preorder, preStart + numsLeft + 1, preEnd, inorder, inRoot + 1, inEnd, inMap);

    return root;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That *warning* has nothing to do with your problem. The actual problem is that `NullPointerException` in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `inorder_map` is missing the last value, because this for loop `for(int i=0;i<inorder.length-1;i++)` should go until be `for(int i = 0; i < inorder.length; i++)`. Because of this, you get a `NullPointerException` when you will try to access the index of the last value from the `inorder` array.

On a side note:

I understand that you are solving LeetCode problems, where the quality of your code does not really matter as long as you get the correct result. Please try to adhere to well-known [Java Coding conventions](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).

Comment: Thank you! That was such a simple mistake from me. Also thank you for sharing the java coding conventions. I will follow it from now on

Answer (score 0):

look at the condition where you exist the for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<inorder.length-1;i++)
        {
            inorder_map.put(inorder[i],i);
        }
```

you did not put all the element into the map bacause `i<inorder.length-1` will exist when `i == inorder.length-1`, that means the element where `i == inorder.length - 1` did not exiest in the map.

we should change the for loop to:

```
for(int i = 0;i <= inorder.length - 1; i++)
{
    inorder_map.put(inorder[i], i);
}
```

or:

```
for(int i = 0;i < inorder.length; i++)
{
    inorder_map.put(inorder[i], i);
}
```